# How do I precompile the Golang standard library?

Tags: go

I'm trying to use Go compiler in a sandboxed environment, but compilation is very slow without a shared build cache directory, because the standard libraries referenced are compiled everytime. I would like to avoid a shared build cache because I want to keep compilations isolated. I asked the question to the Golang team in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64721, they suggest precompiling and distributing the standard library, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried `GOBIN=/tmp/go-std-lib go build std` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I don't know Go much, but how about this: `go tool compile -o stdlib.a -p std`

Comment: To isolate compilations from each other, run each compilation with a unique cache that's initialized from a pre-built cache.

Comment: That's an option, but it would probably be tool slow, the cache size after compiling the standard library is about 122Mb, copying it to each sandbox would be too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library is not precompiled by default, to save the distribution size.

Set the environment variable `GODEBUG=installgoroot=all` to change the default behavior.

Check https://github.com/golang/go/issues/65204 for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I think the GOBIN environment variable is not the correct variable to use for this purpose because GOBIN influences the install location of executables, not compiled packages.

An example of how you could precompile the standard library:

```
# Set up a dedicated directory for the standard library cache
export GOCACHE=/path/to/your/precompiled/std/cache

# Build the standard library
go build -v std
```

Then you could use the precompiled cache in your sandboxed builds:

```
# Point GOCACHE to the precompiled standard library cache
export GOCACHE=/path/to/your/precompiled/std/cache

# Now, go build should use the precompiled standard library and not recompile it
go build your_application
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I've done and it works, but I'm looking for a way to do it without using the build cache if it's possible, I'd like to avoid the cache.

Comment: @ysabih2 can you clarify what you're looking for? You're asking to prebuild packages, that is the definition of what the build cache is, but you're saying you don't want to use the build cache, why not?

Comment: I'm working on a service that runs user-submitted in a sandboxed environment. I've tested the service for a few days and found that the build cache needs to be repopulated regularly even though the sandboxed environment has read-only access to the shared build cache, a cron job seems to work well for that, but I'm searching for a simpler solution.

Comment: @ysabih2 the build cache (like any good cache implementation) is not permanent, go will prune elements from it when they are unused for too long. So it might be that a cron job which periodically rebuilds the thing is the right workaround in your very specific use case.